# How to disable Path MTU Discovery on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, tcpip, mtu

How can I disable [Path MTU Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery) on Windows 10?

Following these instructions for an older Windows version, I tried adding the [`EnablePMTUDiscovery`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc957539(v=technet.10)) registry value to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` and setting it to 0:

[**Disable PMTU Discovery**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/900926/recommended-tcp-ip-settings-for-wan-links-with-a-mtu-size-of-less-than)

> To disable PMTU Discovery, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click **Start**, click **Run**, type regedit, and then click **OK**.
> 2. Locate the following key in the registry:
>
>    **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters**
> 3. On the **Edit** menu, point to **New**, and then click **DWORD Value**.
> 4. Type EnablePMTUDiscovery, and then press ENTER.
> 5. On the **Edit** menu, click **Modify**.
> 6. In the Value data box, type 0, and then click **OK**.
> 7. Quit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer.

But it had no effect, even after restarting the computer.

Comment: For reference: on Linux, Path MTU Discovery can be disabled by setting the [`net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt) sysctl flag to 1:

    `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc=1`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce an [Android networking issue](https://piunikaweb.com/2019/01/16/netflix-or-twitter-not-working-on-your-phone-with-wifi-android-pie-could-be-culprit/) on a Windows PC. So far, I have reproduced it on a Linux PC.

Comment: I have not seen an MTU issue any Windows computer - Just routers and just for Internet VPN connections.